# Minimum Width as padding

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is a box. Inside of that box it has a number. The background size/color is displayed based on the padding. A 1 will obviously be narrower than an 11. Is there anyway to get a minimum width other than using an actual width? So much so that the 1 and 11 will have the same width.

HTML

```
<div class="box">
 <h5>1</h5>
 <h5>11</h5>
</div>
```

CSS

```
h5 {
background-color: white;
padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: the question isn't clear in my opinion; can you please try to explain it better?

Answer (score 1):

There is always the:

```
min-width: 11px;
```

property!

Answer (score 0):

```
.box {
 min-width: 50px;
}

.box h5 {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
```